# android studio 3.1 doesn't show which function cursor is in

Tags: java, android-studio-2.3, android-studio-3.1

In Android Studio 2.3.3 it shows which functions the cursor is in (very nice feature) as shown in the pic below.

[image]

First question, is this a configurable feature? If it is I can't find where. Second question is why do I not see this in Android Studio 3.1? Was this feature removed? Thanks

Comment: Answer from Omar Abdan is correct and it should be enabled by default , but it's placed at the bottom of code screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Studio calls this feature breadcrumbs. you can enable it from the preferences/settings -> breadcrumbs and check show breadcrumbs.

[image: breadcrumbs]